# Setting up Apple TV video JavaScript

Tags: javascript, apple-tv, tvos

I have a simple function that will launch the `player` that handles video playback for the Apple TV

```
function launchPlayer() {
    var player = new Player();
    var playlist = new Playlist();
    var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", "http://localhost:9001/videos/nsoperations.mp4");
    player.playlist = playlist;
    player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
    player.present();
}
```

According to the [**Player Documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/Player), all I needed to play a video back is a player, a playlist[(docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlaylist_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/Playlist), and a media item[(docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/MediaItem). I've got all those, but when running my code, I get an error:
`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` To my understanding, we don't deal with auto-layout for these built in players. Did I use the player wrong?

Full details of error is as follows:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e8f270 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.leading == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e945b0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7f8162e964b0]   (Names: '|':TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e930c0 H:|-(90)-[UIView:0x7f8162e9a640]   (Names: '|':TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e8f270 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.leading == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.leading>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:35:59.886 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e93a20 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e92de0 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e930c0 H:|-(90)-[UIView:0x7f8162e9a640]   (Names: '|':TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e975e0 UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.width == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e93a20 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.trailing>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.024 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e93a20 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e92de0 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e930c0 H:|-(90)-[UIView:0x7f8162e9a640]   (Names: '|':TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e975e0 UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.width == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.width - 2010>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e93a20 UIView:0x7f8162e964b0.trailing == UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.trailing>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.092 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e975e0 UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.width == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.width - 2010>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e23cd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0(1920)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162e975e0 UIView:0x7f8162e9a640.width == TVRelatedContentView:0x7f8162e990a0.width - 2010>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.126 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c8e520 H:|-(>=70)-[UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d40 UIView:0x7f8164226270.width == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816423abd0 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.width == UIView:0x7f8164226270.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164224720 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.127 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425a130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.127 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425a130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.128 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c867b0 V:|-(>=6)-[UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425a130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.138 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51c30 h=--& v=--& H:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c8e520 H:|-(>=70)-[UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d40 UIView:0x7f8164226270.width == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816423abd0 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.width == UIView:0x7f8164226270.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.138 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.139 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c867b0 V:|-(>=6)-[UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.139 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c867b0 V:|-(>=6)-[UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.144 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51c30 h=--& v=--& H:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c8e520 H:|-(>=70)-[UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d40 UIView:0x7f8164226270.width == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816423abd0 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.width == UIView:0x7f8164226270.width>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c0b2f0 UIView:0x7f8162e1dbd0.trailing <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.trailing - 70>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.145 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c87400 V:[_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30(>=80)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.145 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c867b0 V:|-(>=6)-[UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c88760 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.centerY == _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-09-11 07:36:00.146 TestingTVML[3354:323153] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162f51cd0 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c867b0 V:|-(>=6)-[UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190]   (Names: '|':_UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8164266d90 UIView:0x7f8164226270.height == _UIAlertControllerCollectionViewCell:0x7f8164228e10.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f816425e320 _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.height == UIView:0x7f8164226270.height>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8162c86800 UIImageView:0x7f8162e22190.bottom <= _UIAlertControllerActionView:0x7f8162ec3a30.bottom - 6>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.      
  [2]: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlaylist_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/Playlist
  [3]: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/MediaItem
```

Comment: You are running this in local enviroment, yes ? And is http://localhost:9001/videos/nsoperations.mp4 reachable ?

Comment: forgot to add that - yes I'm running local environment, and I've been able to reach `localhost:9001` to deal with other templates.

Comment: I clicked the link you provided, I got the video. Thanks for that nice check!

Comment: `"audio"` is not video, I suppose. You may want to `play` the video.

Comment: @zeroflagL fixed! Thanks for the catch. Now greeted with constraint errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample is ok and do work. Even with the constraint errors, but player is not very forgiving.

I think you're using the Python SimpleHTTPServer for your test, it did not worked for video streaming, but if you use Apache or for example this file directly from apple "http://trailers.apple.com/movies/focus_features/9/9-clip_480p.mov" it will work.

Comment: love you, thanks for the pointer. This is going to help a lot.

Comment: This is correct.  I think video playback requires that the server supports, among other things, byte-range requests.

Comment: Yep, byte range requests are required by video stuff, I remember running into the same problem getting embedded audio/video running in ePub rendering while at Kobo.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turns out that Python's SimpleHTTPServer is not capable of streaming out video and is a poor (minimalist) example to use. I went with `http-server` instead and it works flawlessly. This is the syntax I used (on my Mac):

```
$ npm install http-server -g
$ http-server ./ -p 9001 -a 192.168.16.105
```

where:

`./` is the path to the root of the web server

`-p 9001` is the port you want to use

`-a 192.168.16.105` is the IP address you want to serve from

You can check that it works correctly by opening a web browser and doing something like:

```
http://192.168.16.105:9001/myvideo.mp4
```

*(just make sure you have a video file in that folder to play)*