# How to play YouTube content on tvOS

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, tvos

How would one play a YouTube video on Apple tvOS?

YouTube's embed feature works in iOS 9 as the OS has a UIWebView we can embed it into. 
The new tvOS does not include a UIWebView so I cannot see a way to embed the YouTube video.

Comment: Have you seen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493872/how-do-i-play-a-video-on-tvos-for-apple-tv/32551565#32551565 Just swap the url in 'launchPlayer' to your YouTube url.

Comment: I'm guessing we're going to need a library from Google to do this without violating the Terms of Service.  So it might be a few months while they build this up (along with their own YouTube tvOS app which will come first obviously).

Comment: Plex is able to play YouTube and Vimeo videos from their new [AppleTV App](https://blog.plex.tv/2015/11/02/plex-on-the-new-apple-tv/) via their [Watch Later / Plex It feature](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200392326-Using-the-Plex-It-Bookmarklet).  Based on a quick poke some of their [GitHub souce](https://github.com/plexinc-plugins/Services.bundle/blob/master/Contents/Service%20Sets/com.plexapp.plugins.youtube/URL/YouTube/ServiceCode.pys), it appears they're just doing page scraping. Is that correct? How do they get away with this or has no one noticed?

Comment: @nickv2002 *How do they get away with this or has no one noticed?* Not sure if this is exactly *illegal*, but its frowned upon. At the moment this is the only option if you want to play YouTube/Vimeo content.

Comment: @DanielStorm I was just surprised this worked because the've been on the iOS app store for a while.  Better that we have these workarounds if YouTube doesn't provide an API though.

Comment: this might do more than simply violate their terms of service; I thought users retained their ownership/copyright? if so, and the video is monetized with ads which many videos are then the video owner could potentially sue you for loss of revenue since the ads are missing.

Comment: You can find solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020490/play-youtube-videos-from-my-tvos-application/38764151#38764151 .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/UIKit.html) and [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://MediaPlayer%20Changes%20for%20Objective-C) are not available for tvOS. Our next option is to use `AVPlayer` to play YouTube videos.

`AVPlayer` cannot play a YouTube video from a standard YouTube URL, ie. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE`. It needs a direct URL to the video file. Using [HCYoutubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser) we can accomplish exactly that. Once we have the URL we need, we can play it with our `AVPlayer` like so:

```c
NSString *youTubeString = @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE";
NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:youTubeString]];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [videos objectForKey:@"medium"]];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:videoPlayer];
avPlayerLayer.frame = playerView.layer.bounds;
[playerView.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];

[videoPlayer play];
```

Note that this is **NOT** allowed under [YouTube's TOS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). **Use it at your own risk**. Your app may stop working at any point if YouTube notices you are not following the TOS or if YouTube changes the embed code it generates.

Comment: Is HCYoutubeParser still being supported? Doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @Shazam it has not been updated in over 2 years on GitHub so some issues may exist.

Comment: Know any library that can run on tvOS? Like GTLYouTube or something?

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh at the moment, no. All iOS YouTube players use a `UIWebView` so they are not applicable for tvOS. I'd anticipate that YouTube will release it's own library for tvOS at some point as they've done for iOS [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

Comment: Can anyone point me to part of YouTube docs that is violated by this libraries?

Comment: How exactly does Youtube ban the app from working? Since there is not an API key. IP address perhaps?

Answer (score 18):

Swift 2.0 version of Daniel Storm's answer:

```
let youTubeString : String = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8To-6VIJZRE"
let videos : NSDictionary = HCYoutubeParser.h264videosWithYoutubeURL(NSURL(string: youTubeString))
let urlString : String = videos["medium"] as! String
let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)

let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset:asset)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
let avPlayerLayer  = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);
self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
avPlayer.play()
```

Comment: How did you set up HCYoutubeParser to import into Swift?  Tried with CocoaPods but the `use_frameworks!` stuff breaks my existing Obj-C code.

Answer (score 8):

[XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) has been a popular way to directly play a YouTube video on iOS for a while, and the developer recently updated it to support the new AppleTV.

Here's the code from the [Objective-C example](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/1d784c24cc6d6dd0567fec019ed29bbfd1386e89/XCDYouTubeKit%20Demo/tvOS%20Demo/PlaylistCollectionViewController.m#L70-L86):

```cpp
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
[self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

__weak AVPlayerViewController *weakPlayerViewController = playerViewController;
[[XCDYouTubeClient defaultClient] getVideoWithIdentifier:playlistItem.snippet.resourceId.videoId completionHandler:^(XCDYouTubeVideo * _Nullable video, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (video)
    {
        NSDictionary *streamURLs = video.streamURLs;
        NSURL *streamURL = streamURLs[XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHTTPLiveStreaming] ?: streamURLs[@(XCDYouTubeVideoQualityHD720)] ?: streamURLs[@(XCDYouTubeVideoQualityMedium360)] ?: streamURLs[@(XCDYouTubeVideoQualitySmall240)];
        weakPlayerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamURL];
        [weakPlayerViewController.player play];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

[Swift example here.](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/157#issuecomment-144160209)

Comment: If you're trying to play YT content from a TVML/TVJS interface, here's [a Gist that shows how](https://gist.github.com/nickv2002/b7bb28cdccc000bdb910).

Comment: This will also violate the youtube TOS, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, XCDYouTubeKit does.  See also: [Discussion of Apple approval for apps using XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/121)

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, even an Apple Staff person echoed the “negative” on this. From an [Apple Developer Forums thread on the topic](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17027):

> There is no support for WebViews on tvOS, and so an iframe implementation will not work. TVML does not offer this capability.

Answer (score 4):

After some trying I'm happy to announce that:

```
youtube://watch/video_id
```

will open the YouTube app and play the YouTube video.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably currently the only reliable solution on tvOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, someone didn't understand it, since my answer (which came from my investigation and tests) -1ed my answer. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Daniel Storm's answer, you can also achieve this with the new TVML language using the code:

```
<lockup videoURL="http://mp4-url.mp4">
<img src="video thumbnail.jpg" />
</lockup>
```

(for this to work you'll need the direct video file (mp4) which also is not allowed by the Youtube TOS)

EDIT, found also the .JS solution:
[How do I play a video on tvOS for Apple TV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493872/how-do-i-play-a-video-on-tvos-for-apple-tv?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I used this one https://cocoapods.org/pods/youtube-parser

```
Youtube.h264videosWithYoutubeURL(testURL) { (videoInfo, error) -> Void in
    if let videoURLString = videoInfo?["url"] as? String,
         videoTitle = videoInfo?["title"] as? String {
             print("\(videoTitle)")
             print("\(videoURLString)")
             self.playVideo(videoURLString)
    }
}
```