# YouTube URL Scheme tvOS

Tags: objective-c, youtube, url-scheme, tvos

I am trying to open YouTube's app from my application with the URL scheme or the YouTube.com domain which opens YouTube's app directly on an iOS device.

This is the code I tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://results?search_query=trailer+%@",movieTitle]]];
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=trailer+%@",movieTitle]]];
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how to retrieve the URL scheme for YouTube's tvOS application?

Comment: If you're able to get a hold of the `.ipa` you could look at the `.plist` to see what the URL Scheme is exactly or if there even is one.

Comment: What do you mean get a hold of the ipa?

Comment: [.ipa - file extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension%29). If you were able to get this you could unzip it and see the `.plist`.

Comment: I know what .ipa is but getting the Youtube's IPA without jailbreaking it won't be easy

Comment: I'm not sure if you're able to backup an Apple TV to iTunes but if that's possible you can obtain the `.ipa`.

Comment: It seems that Apple TV 4 is not backing up on iTunes :/

Comment: I have a question. Have you tried url schemes like `tel` or `itms`? Do they work?

Comment: I've tried every URL Scheme I could find for YouTube, new and old, with no success. I also contacted YouTube's dev team with no response. I'd guess there is no URL Scheme for YouTube's tvOS application at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos)

Answer (score 4):

On Apple TV you can use this URL scheme to play a YouTube video in the YouTube app:

```
youtube://watch/video_id
```

Code example:

```
func playVideoInYouTube(_ identifier: String) {

    if let url = URL(string: "youtube://watch/" + identifier),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    else {
        // Inform the user about missing YouTube app
    }
}
```

To use the `canOpenURL` method, you have to add the scheme to the **Info.plist** file under key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, as part of a schemes array. In XML it looks like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>youtube</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This is excellent and works. However to really be functional I am wondering if there is a way for my app to "know" when the video has completed playing and therefore to start another video? Simply put, if my app has a list of videoid's - can I cue them up / control them on the YouTube app?

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily positing this as a “correct" answer, but I think all YouTube links, on iOS at least, are handled by `http`, not something like `youtube://`.

Source (looks to be from June 2015):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html

Comment: `youtube://` does indeed open the YouTube application on iOS. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://"]];`

Comment: Any evidence to suggest that scheme supports opening anything besides the app, though? Any kind of deep links, etc.?

Comment: Well, kind of... `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Rm3-HA"]];`

Comment: So it’s a direct swap for the `http` requests, looks like?

Comment: They probably built the tvOS app too fast for the tvOS launch that they cut off some features like this one. I think there is no reason not to implement it.

Comment: That, or they want people using their own app for a little while, while the platform matures. Don’t want to fragment too much early on?

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's missing. I am wondering how restrictive it would be to distribute tvos apps that access the youtube content directly and hence break their TOS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered some issues playing youtube videos in the youtube app but I found a workaround, I used the XCDYouTubeKit library to play the youtube video's directly in my app. It's very easy to use and works fine so far.

XCDYouTubeKit : https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit