# Launch YouTube app from other app

Tags: youtube, tvos

Is there a way to start playing a YouTube video in the YouTube app from another app? It's possible in iOS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone), but how would I do this with tvOS?

Comment: Related: [YouTube URL Scheme tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34473037/2108547).

Comment: Thanks, I hope it will be resolved soon.