# How to show a Vimeo video in an Apple TV app

Tags: vimeo, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to show a Vimeo video with a sample app for Apple TM.

This is my code:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
<catalogTemplate>
    <banner>
        <title>RWDevConHighlights</title>
    </banner>
    //add stuff here
    //1.
    <list>
        <section>
            //2.
            <listItemLockup>
                <title>Inspiration Videos</title>
                <decorationLabel>4</decorationLabel>
                <relatedContent>
                    <grid>
                        <section>
                            //2
                            <lockup videoURL="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4">
                                <img src="${this.BASEURL}images/ray.png" width="500" height="308" />
                            </lockup>
                        </section>
                    </grid>
                </relatedContent>
            </listItemLockup>
        </section>
    </list>
</catalogTemplate>
</document>`
};
```

This doesn't work:

```
<lockup videoURL="https://vimeo.com/176253524">
                            <img src="${this.BASEURL}images/ray.png" width="500" height="308" />
                        </lockup>
```

How can I integrate a Vimeo video?

Comment: I'd imagine you would need the direct video file url: [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32537719/2108547).

Comment: If that's *your* video then Vimeo will provide a signed URL that you can put into an external video player. Otherwise, it's not meant to be possible.

Comment: It is my video and i ca get a url for direct link with own player. I i copy this link into my browser, the video will be shown. But if I put the url into "videoURL", the app does not start. I think it has to do something with the parameters into the url or with the https.

Comment: Ah, there is a http live streaming address. If i use this, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the vimeo.com you can press button "Share" and get a correct link to your video. So, I think you should use https://player.vimeo.com/video/176253524 instead of your url.