# Play YouTube videos with tvOS without breaching privacy policy

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, tvos

I am working on a tvOS application where I have to play videos from a company's own YouTube channel. As tvOS has no UIWebKit framework, and YouTube doesn't have any SDK's for tvOS, the only choice I am left with is to get access to MP4 format videos of the YouTube videos. YouTube gives access to download your own videos from your own channel but it can only be done manually. Is there any way to get access to YouTube videos using tvOS or download your own videos using code without breaching any privacy policies?

Comment: Not YouTube bashing here, but you might consider hosting your video elsewhere. By using mp4 download instead of a streaming protocol, you'll see poor video performance at best.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But HCYouTubeParser is breaching YouTube Privacy Policy, and tvOS Doesn't approve any applications that use these kind of API's. Look at 8.6 in [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not download MP4 files from the YouTube. There are a lot of abilities how to play YouTube videos in tvOS applications, you can find some of them here: [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos) .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But HCYouTubeParser is breaching YouTube Privacy Policy, and tvOS Doesn't approve any applications that use these kind of API's. Look at 8.6 in  [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/)

Comment: What code did you used to play videos that was aborted by Apple?

Comment: I haven't used any code yet! but it is said in the apple website that they wont approve such apps!