# YouTube API on tvOS?

Tags: youtube, tvos

Could one make an app with YouTube functionality for an apple TV?

I can't find any definite up to date information with an answer... or an answer that doesn't violate the terms of service.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537719/2108547)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of February 2018, **there is nothing**. I faced same problem 2 years ago and was not able to fix it without violating their Terms of Service.

What makes it even more frustrating is that YouTube is not willing to give an answer on it.

There is a YouTube library for iOS available [here](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) and there are various open issues (like [here](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/148)) regarding tvOS support - but again, YouTube does not bother to address them.

Comment: Unfortunate. Thank you for the answer!