# play youtube video in tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos, avkit

I am facing some trouble with playing youtube videos in my tvOS app. 
I am using the popular [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) to get the stream URL as shown below.

```
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoIdentifier) { [weak playerViewController] (video, error) in
        if(video != nil) {
            let streamURLs = video?.streamURLs
            if let streamURL = streamURLs![278] {
                print(streamURL)
                playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: streamURL)
            }
        }else {
            self.printLog(logEntry: "Video not found")
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Runs with a log entry

> Task <2C60AFA3-B5B0-4D46-BB54-BCB72FDC6FC3>.<1> finished with error - code: -999

The log doesn't explain much. How to play a youtube video from a tvOS app?

Comment: have you tried with AVKit?

Comment: I have used avkit, updated the code

Comment: Ok, What is the best of playing a youtube video from your tvOS app?

Comment: @Neelesh I don't know, I live in China and not only Youtube is blocked by all ISP, but Apple doesn't sell the AppleTV here (you can see it's missing from https://www.apple.com/cn/). Try to read https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537719/2108547)

Comment: https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/issues/157#issuecomment-144160209