# Play YouTube videos from my tvOS application

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, tvos

I want to play YouTube videos from my tvOS application. I found to play URL videos by [AVPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493872/how-do-i-play-a-video-on-tvos-for-apple-tv), but not getting to play YouTube videos since UIWebView is not supported on tvOS. I don't want to use any third party libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube content on tvOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [YoutubeSourceParserKit](https://github.com/mojilala/YoutubeSourceParserKit) to parse data that you receive from url. Then you will have the url and you will be able to play video with the following code (Swift 2 solution for tvOS 9):

```
    Youtube.h264videosWithYoutubeURL(NSURL.init(string: "https://www.youtube.com/any-video-url")!) 
    { (videoInfo, error) -> Void in
        if let videoURLString = videoInfo?["url"] as? String,
            videoTitle = videoInfo?["title"] as? String {

            let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLString)
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
            }
        }
    }
```